# Rmarkdown rticles - MDPI template. How to print your own abbreviations

Tags: templates, latex, r-markdown

I am using the MDPI template (from the rticles package), and keen to also use the glossaries packages so I don't have to manually feed all the abbreviation on the appropriate YAML field.

For such, I have loaded the LaTex package glossaries using the header-includes:

```
header-includes:
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym, section=section]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makeglossaries
\makeindex
\input{glossary}
```

after creating several acronyms within the Rmarkdown body, I would be willing to either input the latex commands and have it printed in within the "Abbreviations" section of the template.

Currently, I am able to hack it through the following steps (I am sure there is a better way):

1- keep all the aux files chunk with :

```
 options(tinytex.clean = FALSE)
```

2- cmd  `makeglossaries "filename"`

3- Raw Latex on Rmarkdown file:

```
\begin{abbreviations}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={}]

\end{abbreviations}
```

However, I would be keen to know if I could insert something on the YAML and use the MDPI formatting.
Alternatively, I could edit the rticles MDPI template (but I am not sure how).

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide a [mre] or clear steps for reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Include in YAML:

`include-after: glossary.tex`

I tried without success, but it seems reasonable that this approach might work with a  few modifications